# In Visual Studio Code run Node.js, call python script as child-process and debug it

Tags: python, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, child-process

I'd like to jump into the python code as soon as the child process is created by nodejs to debug the python code

Server.js:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["MyPythonFile.py"]);
console.log("Finished!")
```

MyPythonFile.py:

```
print("First line I'd like to debug")
print("Second line I'd like to debug")
print("Third line I'd like to debug")
```

Both, Server.js and MyPythonFile.py, are in the same directory
Is there any way to tell visual studio code to attach the python file to the debugger or create a new debugger instance for the python code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to debug the script as a [remote debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-debugging) situation. If you're willing to start the service outside of VS code you can attach to it like a [local script](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_attach-to-a-local-script).

Comment: Thanks, seems to do what I am trying to do . I'll give it a try.